# Screenshots are not visible in klov reports

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, extentreports, extent, selenium-extent-report

Screenshots are not getting uploaded in klov report :

Getting below warning :

> [testng] Jul 05, 2018 12:34:29 PM com.aventstack.extentreports.mediastorage.HttpMediaManagerKlov storeMedia
>   [testng] WARNING: Unable to upload file to server C:\V2AutoWK/temp//screenshots/HLT_01--Failed_AT-VerifyTitle--0507_123427_PM(IST).png

The file is getting saved in db but unable to upload in klov report.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Check your File Path : `C:\V2AutoWK/temp//screenshots/HLT_01--Failed_AT-VerifyTitle--0507_123427_PM(IST).png`

Which seems incorrect slashes with combination of Forward and Backward slashes.

The effective way is, You can store image within your project folder by absolute path.

```
public void takeScreenShot(String SSName) throws Exception
    {
        File screen = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(screen);
        File filetest = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toFile();
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(filetest + "\\Screenshots\\" + " - " + SSName + ".png"));
        testlog.info("Details of " + SSName, MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Screenshots\\"  + " - " + SSName + ".png").build());
    }
```

Screenshot is fetched by ExtentReport method. You can find similar for klov.

Comment: Hi Ishita, Thanks for your inputs, I tried with your code as well, still getting the same error.                        
Jul 05, 2018 3:35:05 PM com.aventstack.extentreports.mediastorage.HttpMediaManagerKlov storeMedia
WARNING: Unable to upload file to server C:\V2AutoWK\temp\screenshots\Error.png

Comment: Please share your trial code, To retrieve image in Report

Comment: scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(scrFile);

File filetest = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toFile();

System.out.println("filetest returned is "+filetest);

ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(filetest + "\\temp\\screenshots\\Error.png"));

test.log(Status.ERROR,"Details of " + shortTcName, MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\temp\\screenshots\\Error.png").build());

Comment: You have made mistake in your code, Keep separate ".png" extension on both last line

Comment: Just for your info..with my previous code and your above provided code , screenshot is being attached successfully in html report(normal extent report).

Comment: Hi Ishita, i really appreciate your prompt help and support. I tried as below by putting separate ".png" extension for both lines but still no success.
---------------------
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(filetest + "\\temp\\screenshots\\Error"+".png"));

test.log(Status.ERROR,"Details of " + shortTcName, MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\temp\\screenshots\\Error"+".png").build());
---------------------

Comment: Just for your update: With your code, Image is shown as small thumbnill in Klov (localhost:90). But when i click on it open a small 10x10 blank image. 
Note: Images are appearing correctly in extent HTML Report

Comment: @Tanveer If you think provided assistance has helped you to solve problem, Please accept answer.

Comment: Hi Ishita, There is already same issue is logged in Klov as bug and is Still in OPEN state:
https://github.com/anshooarora/klov/issues/45

Comment: @Tanveer a fix has been released, please try with the latest.  3.1.6-SNAPSHOT. See #45 you referenced.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug reported here: https://github.com/anshooarora/klov/issues/45

Hope that will be fixed soon!

Update: a fix has already been released with 3.1.6-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: This is an issue with the path..  issue you've referenced is not related to the above question.